# How can I drag file from Nautilus to Brasero?

Tags: nautilus, drag-and-drop

I want to drag a file from Nautilus to Brasero in Ubuntu 12.04 when both windows are open.

The only way to do it that I know currently is to maximize Brasero and left the Nautilus open (but not minimized) and so I can drag the file to the window that it is below, but I wonder if there is a more quick way to do it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After we opened a new *"Data Project"* from Brasero we see the following empty window:

[image]

We can now easily drag and drop files, directories, or multiple selections to this space.

---

Alternatively there also is a right click option on selected files *"Send to..."* where we are able to send these to the *"CD/DVD Creator"*.

---

In case we need to work with full screen application we may use Nautilus option *"View -> Extra Pane"* to open the location `burn:///`. We can open this location, drag and drop files from the second pane and choose to write to the disc from Nautilus in case we inserted a blank disc.

[image]

---

In case we had the Brasero icon attached to the Launcher (choose *"Lock to Launcher"* on the right click menu that pops up when you click on the icon of a running application) we can also drag and drop files to this icon on the Launcher. This will then open Brasero with the files we had dragged in the project window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help!I know how to send files to Brasero, but I wonder if there is some way of doing it having both windows maximixed. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: See edit - no need to open a Brasero window ;)

Comment: Wow! I would not ever imagined that burning files in Brasero could be done that way! I still would like to know if the simple drag-and-drop method could be used to drag files from Nautilus to Brasero. In previous releases of Ubuntu, I used to drag the file from Nautilus to the Brasero minimized window in order to open the Brasero window and drop there the file. However, this does not seem possible when using Unity. The problem, I guess, it that there is no way of opening another window while you drag a file, I still wonder if there is wome way of doing it.

Comment: @granadajose: all ways lead to Rome ;) See edit for another method.